# Can I read any readable valid memory location via a (unsigned) char* in C++?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, void-pointers, memory-access

My search foo seems lacking today.

I would like to know if it is *legal* according to std C++ to inspect "any" memory location via an (unsigned(?)) char*. By *any* location I mean any *valid* address of an object or array (or inside an array) inside the program.

By way of example:

```
void passAnyObjectOrArrayOrSomethingElseValid(void* pObj) {
   unsigned char* pMemory = static_cast<unsigned char*>(pObj)
   MyTypeIdentifyier x = tryToFigureOutWhatThisIs(pMemory);
}
```

**Disclaimer**: This question is purely academical. I do not intend to put this into production code! By *legal* I mean if it's really *legal* according to the standard, that is if it would work on 100% of all implementations. (Not just on x86 or some common hardware.)

Sub-question: Is `static_cast` the right tool to get from the void* address to the char* pointer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ assumes strict aliasing, which means that two pointers of fundamentally different type do not alias the same value.

However, as correctly pointed out by bdonlan, the standard makes an exception for `char` and `unsigned char` pointers.

Thus, in general this is undefined behaviour for any pointer type to read *any deliberate* address (which might be any type), but for the particular case of `unsigned char` as in the question it is **allowed** (ISO 14882:2003 3.10(15)).

`static_cast` does compile-time type checking, so it is unlikely to always work. In such a case, you will want `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: That's not true- anyone who comes up with a better idea can search for `reinterpret_cast`- they can't search for C-style casts. In addition, C-style casts can become even worse casts without warning, like `const_cast`.

Comment: Good point... being able to _text search_ for `reinterpret_cast` is a big big plus, I'd never have thought of that.

Comment: `unsigned char` and `char` are permitted to alias with any other type; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E) §6.5/7, last bullet as well as footnote 73. It is however undefined behavior to pass an arbitrary address (ie, one not derived from taking an address of a valid object) for other reasons (§6.5.6/8, §6.5.3.2/4, etc)

Comment: Note that 9899:1999 is the C99 spec, not C++, but it's likely to be the same, since C++ tries to be generally compatible when it comes to semantics...

Comment: You're right, that would be ISO 14882:2003 3.10(15), I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Damon: q("`static_cast` does compile-time type checking, so it is unlikely ...") -- since I pass a `void*` there is nothing `static_cast` could check. The question here really is whether to use `static_c` or `reinterpret_c` and since I do not need *any* cast to get from an object to a void-pointer (i.e. `void* p = &object;` is valid) I thought `static_c` is more appropriate than `reinterpret_c`. Obviously, if I directly cast an object to a char-type, I need `reinterpret_c` so that may be an argument to also use `reinterpret_c` here.

Answer (score 2):

Per ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E) §6.5/7:

> 7. An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - [...]
> - a character type

So it is legal (in C) to dereference and examine a (valid) pointer via `unsigned char`. However, the contents you'll find there are unspecified; `tryToFigureOutWhatThisIs` has no well-defined way of actually figuring out what it's looking at. I don't have a copy of the C++ spec here, but I suspect it uses the same definition, in order to maintain compatibility.

Comment: C++ has similar language: "a char or unsigned char type" rather than "a character type"

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a `char*`, not an `unsigned char*`. Using an `unsigned char*` will break strict aliasing rules and invoke undefined behaviour, but there is an exception for `char*`. However, trying to actually do anything with the memory you read is very highly dubious and very likely to do something undefined. That's why it's rarely done in idiomatic C++ code.

Comment: hmm, sure about that? I thought the exception applied for unsigned char as well. (Don't think I ever actually looked it up however)

Comment: @jalf: I'm pretty sure that I saw a Standard quote and it only said `char*`.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E) §6.5/7 references "a character type"; this allows for either signed or unsigned accesses. It's not the C++ spec, but it's likely to be the same...

Comment: In both C++03 and C++11 it is definitely `char` and `unsigned char`.  Apparently, `signed char` is bad even if `char` is a signed type.  3.10 [basic.lval]/15 in C++03, 3.10 [basic.lval]/10 in C++11

Comment: @Dennis, @bdonlan: thanks, very helpful. I asked because I wasn't sure, so great to see the relevant standard quotes. :)